# ETL to bigquery using airflow without have permission cloud storage/ cloud sql

Tags: mysql, python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, apache-airflow

i have done ETL from MySql to bigQuery with python, but because i haven't permission to connect google cloud storage/ cloud sql, i must dump data and partition that by last date, this way easy but didn't worth it because take a much time, i want to ETL using airflow from MySql/mongo to bigQuery without google cloud storage/ cloud sql it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) (which is used under [Cloud Composer in Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/composer/)) is generally used to schedule a migration. The actual migration along the complete ETL procedure can be performed with [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) (which uses Apache Beam) and  is the recommended tool for this use case. [Here is a complete tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/performing-etl-from-relational-database-into-bigquery) for performing a ETL procedure from a relational database (such as MySQL) into BigQuery using Cloud Dataflow.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, how about if my source from mongodb and mysql ? can i keep doing this tutorial ? @PYB

Comment: The tutorial is valid for any relational database, such as MySQL. For MongoDB, see all the options for loading data into BigQuery here (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data), which will guide you in building your process.